# Windows XP, classic theme, empty space at the bottom of taskbar, caused by language bar

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, taskbar, themes, user-interface

I have to use Windows XP for work reasons and this UI bug is a small but constant annoyance.

When classic theme is enabled, taskbar elements don't align with the size of the taskbar, leaving a few pixels of inactive space at the bottom of the screen.
Standard classic theme, unmodified.

The language panel is responsible for this. If you remove it, the gap disappears and doesn't appear when you restore the panel if taskbar's locked. Tray icons appearing or disappearing enlarge the taskbar again.

I'd ignore it if it was purely cosmetic, but it's not.
Every time I overshoot and click at nothing I think back on the times when you could point at things at the screen's edge by flicking cursor in their general direction.

Naturally, I don't want to keep removing/restoring the language bar forever, all the time. Don't want to remove it either.
Can it be fixed permanently or do I have to keep using the Windows XP theme, an ugly reminder of my failure to solve this?